# how to overcome this "subscript out of bound" error in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

i have a list of 10 data frames with names as q1,q2,q3....q9,q10.
all these data frames are of same structure with two columns: "word" and "count".
Now i want to print the first 5 rows' values. I also want to print the iteration count of the for loop. But when i'm running the following for-loop, i'm getting an error as
**Error in nam[["word"]] : Subscript out of bounds**

```
for(x in 1:10){
  for(y in 1:5){
  nam<-paste("q",x,sep = "")
  print(nam[["word"]][y])
  print(nam[["count"]][y]) 
  print(y)
}}
```

And when i change my code for addressing my data frames like this, i get the error as **Error in nam$word : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

```
for(x in 1:10){
  for(y in 1:5){
  nam<-paste("q",x,sep = "")
  print(nam2$word[y])
  print(nam2$count[y])
  print(y)
}}
```

Please suggest how i can avoid/overcome this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks,
Aman

Comment: Welcome to the horrors of R syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `nam` is just a character here, you need to use `get` function to get the actual data.frame first:

```
for(x in 1:10){
  for(y in 1:5){
  nam<-paste("q",x,sep = "")
  print(get(nam)[["word"]][y])
  print(get(nam)[["count"]][y]) 
  print(y)
}}
```

Another way to accomplish what you want to see which avoids for loop:

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) head(get(paste0("q", i)), 5))
```

Or:

```
lapply(mget(paste0("q", 1:10)), head, 5)
```